# How to extract this parameter value in php

Tags: php

I have a url that looks like this, where comment=token3u8324349809832409 by they're separated by `/`. How can I extract the token value `token3u8324349809832409`?

```
$saved_string = "http://site.com/id/12345/comment/token3u8324349809832409"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$new_string = explode ( "/" , $saved_string );
$token = $new_string[count($new_string)-1];
```

Comment: what if /comment/... is not at the end ? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions:

```
$saved_string = "http://site.com/id/12345/comment/token3u8324349809832409";

preg_match('/(token[a-z0-9]+)/', $saved_string, $matches);
$token = $matches[1];

// $token = 'token3u8324349809832409';
```

Comment: what if the url is `http://site.com/id/12345/foo/token123/comment/token3u8324349809832409` ? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$saved_string = "http://site.com/id/12345/comment/token3u8324349809832409"

$ar =  split("/", $saved_string);
$token = $ar[count($ar)-1];
```

I hope this helps

Comment: what if /comment/... is not at the end ? :-) (also, [`split()`](http://php.net/split) is deprecated; use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) or [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) instead.)

Comment: it will take last parameter from url, it doesnt matter is it token or something else, you will get it. or if you have 1000 params before last one this will take last one. Simple logic length of array - 1 that is last param of array, because counting starts from 0

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
if (preg_match('#/comment/([^/]+)#', $saved_string, $matches)) {
    $comment = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the last part, you could use

```
$value = end(explode('/', $saved_string));
```

or: (from the top of my head...)

```
preg_match('/\/token(.*)/', $saved_string, $value);
```

Comment: Both will work only if /comment/... is at the end ;-) (the second form will match anything after `/comment/token` until the end of the string.)

Comment: "If it's always the last part" - I know that ;x